# convert html to plain text jquery .ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, htmltext

Please find the below jQuery code. Sending email perfectly, but I see a whole bunch of code (HTML) in the email. I want to convert the `html()` output of `#right` to `text()`. How can I do that?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.confirm_button').click(function () {
        var student_name = $.trim($('#student_name').val());
        var student_contact = $.trim($('#student_contact').val());
        var student_email = $.trim($('#student_email').val());
        var right = $('#right').html();

        if (student_name.length < 3 || student_contact.length < 8 || student_email.length < 4)
        {
            $('#sendfail').attr('title', 'Sending Failed!').text('Please Enter valid information. All fields are required').dialog({
                buttons: {
                    'Ok': function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        $location.reload(true);
                    }
                },
                closeOnEscape: true,
                draggable: false,
                resizable: false,
                modal: true
            });
        }
        else
        {
            var objAjaxRequestData = {
                'student_name': student_name,
                'student_contact': student_contact,
                'student_email': student_email,
                'right': right
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'send-select-university.php',
                data: objAjaxRequestData,
                success: function () {
                    $('#sendsuccess')
                            .attr('title', 'Message sent successfully')
                            .text('Your message has been sent. We will be in touch soon')
                            .dialog({
                                buttons: {
                                    'Ok': function () {
                                        $(this).dialog('close');
                                        window.location = "http://www.ankooverseas.com";
                                    }
                                },
                                closeOnEscape: true,
                                draggable: false,
                                resizable: false,
                                modal: true
                            });
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Oops request sending failed. Please check your internet connection and try again');
                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Try this For Parsing Html -  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

Comment: If you set the email to send as HTML, it will use the HTML to render the message properly instead of showing you the source code. In PHPMailer you just need to call `$mail->isHTML();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace

`var right=$('#right').html();`

to the

`var right=$('#right').text();`

According to your comments, I think you would be better to use the following code to have the selected items in a formatted view:

```
var right = "";
$("#shortlist_univs").children().each(function (i, univ) { // iterate over all universities and add them to the output variable in a list-like view.
  right += $(univ).text() + "\n"
});
```

Comment: i tried it as well. but it looks like a paragraph. which is difficult to understand for me.

Comment: @user1812111 do you want the text to have some kind of formatting? What do you mean in the "looks like a paragraph"?

Comment: i have to send the text of this div via email. So if i use  text(). i see this as a paragraph instead of items. look at this http://www.ankooverseas.com/select_university i am trying to grab the text of the right column under selected universities.

Comment: @user1812111 Did you try the updated answer? It now does the formatting of the text as a list, not as a paragraph.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks so much. You saved me.